# How load data when a React component prop changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i link to a new component, then all is fine. But when i am inside a component, then i cannot use NavLink.
Inside a component, where only the subitem.id is changed, i can do this or manuelly.

```
<a href={'/unternehmen/' + anzeigen.unternehmen.id + '/stellen/' + subitem.id}><button type="button" className="btn gColor btn-md">Read more</button></a>
```

When i use NavLink in this way:

```
<NavLink to={'/unternehmen/' + anzeigen.unternehmen.id + '/stellen/' + subitem.id}><button type="button" className="btn gColor btn-md">Read more Navlink</button></NavLink>
```

Then the URL is changed, but nothing else happens.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    const API = 'http://localhost:8080/';
    const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'stellen/';
    
    export const UnternehmenStellenContext = React.createContext();
    
    export default class UnternehmenStellenProvider extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          id: props.id,
          anzeigen: [],
          isLoading: false,
        }
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.loadResource();
      }
      loadResource() {
        fetch(API + DEFAULT_QUERY + this.state.id)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({ anzeigen: data, isLoading: false }));
      }
    
      componentDidUpdate(prevState, nextProps) {
        if (prevState.id !== nextProps.id) {
          this.setState({
            id: this.state.id
          });
        }
      }
    
      render() {    
        return (
          <UnternehmenStellenContext.Provider value={this.state}>
            {this.props.children}
          </UnternehmenStellenContext.Provider>
        );
      }
    }
```

componentDidUpdate doesn't seem to do anything.

My routing:

```
<Switch>            
<Route key="stellen" exact path='/unternehmen/:id/stellen/:id' component={(stellenProps) => <UnternehmenStellenDisplay id={stellenProps.match.params.id} />} />
 </Switch>
```

Comment: You need to call `this.loadResource` after updating the state

Comment: There is an event called `componentWillReceiveProps`. It is fired when the component props changes.

Comment: Thank you, i tried with componentWillReceiveProps, but somehow without success. How do I call this.loadResource? My problem is, when i call subitem within subitem.That is maybe tricky, but is all fine, when i type the URL manually.